# Problem with dual resolution screen on laptop - external screen on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display-resolution

I am not able to make dual screen work. Mirrored display work, but when splitting the screen, the resolution gets all messed up.

Monitor pictures: 
https://i.imgur.com/K5yHB6A.jpg
https://i.imgur.com/WjWHQdd.jpg

Basically the external monitor "overflows" on the laptop screen

Here are the various informations about my system:

Graphics Card GeForce GTX1060

Driver version: version 381.22 from nvidia-381 (open source)

```
uname -a
Linux jb-laptop 4.4.25-040425-generic #201610161231 SMP Sun Oct 16 16:33:39 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I've searched for a long time here to find a solution to my problem but haven't had any luck so far.

I've tried upgrading the kernel, upgrading - downgrading to a different nvidia driver, tried to fiddle with the xrandr config settings.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NVIDIA binary driver version 384.59 was recently released and that fixed my issue (no further action was required).